# Extracting $P_0$ from generating function

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions

I have the following generating function for stochastic process

$$\sum_n z^n p_n=\left[1-\frac{(1-z)}{\Lambda(t)}\right]^{n_0},$$

and I want to extract the probability $p_0(t)$ but I am confused how I could do this. So far I've thought of

$$p_0(t)=\sum_n z^n p_n \delta_{n, 0},$$

to extract it but that doesn't seem to help solve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you evaluate at $z=0$?

Comment: @Phicar Wow! I'm embarrassed. I knew it was something simple but my brain just wouldn't let me. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, happens to me all the time. Welcome here!

Comment: @RobPratt Ok, I have done so Rob. Thanks for caring.

Comment: Yep, just gave you a +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluate at $z=0$ in your first expression. Notice that for $n>0$, one has $0^n=0$ and the only term remaining is the constant term $p_0$.